# EF Core Join while selecting only the join table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have three models (minimised):

```
[Table("People")]
public class Person
{    
    [Key]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

[Table("PersonAddresses")]
public class PersonAddress
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public int? IsCurrent { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateRecorded { get; set; }
}

[Table("Addresses")]
public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public PostCode PostCode { get; set; }
    public string PostNameOrNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to do a join between `PersonAddresses` and `Address` which leaves me only with a list / queryable of `Address` types.

I managed to get an anonymous type collection of both `PersonAddress` and `Address` by using a tutorial but I'm sure there's a simple amendment to the below query which gives me what I want:

```
        var anonTypeOfTwoTables = _context.PersonAddresses
            .Where(x => x.Person.PersonId == personId)
            .Join(_context.Addresses,
            person => person.Person.PersonId,
            address => address.AddressId,
            (address, personAddress) => new
            {
                Address = address,
                PersonAddress = personAddress
            });
```

where `personId` is just an int passed to the encompassing method.

Can I get the query to just return `List<Address> addresses = _context...` instead of `var anonTypeOfTwoTables...`

Comment: Why are you creating an anonymous type with both records if you specifically only want the Address? Why not `(address, personAddress) => Address`?

Comment: I don't know why, I was just following a tutorial on joining!

Comment: If you're not careful, such tutorials will lead you into a solution first, problem second style of programming. Such seems to be the case here as you also don't need an explicit join to accomplish your goal. See the answer by @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu

Comment: It was the closest thing I found to what I wanted, but I couldn't figure out how to minimise it to exactly what I wanted. If I had done that I wouldn't have needed to ask the question :D - the answer has helped me discover the joys of EF, I was even able to employ it and select across three tables without using a join in another part of the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you made the mapping configuration of your EF model, you don't need to explicitly call join.

```
 var anonTypeOfTwoTables = _context.PersonAddresses
        .Where(x => x.Person.PersonId == personId)
        .Join(_context.Addresses,
        person => person.Person.PersonId,
        address => address.AddressId,
        (address, personAddress) => new
        {
            Address = address,
            PersonAddress = personAddress
        });
```

turns out to be

```
var anonTypeOfTwoTables = _context.PersonAddresses
        .Where(x => x.Person.PersonId == personId)
        .Select( x => new {
            PersonAddress = x,
            Address = x.Address
        });
```